# Regex - Match one string but capture multiple occurences of another (.NET)

Tags: .net, regex

Given a string:

12345XXX3256|221456000|352456345|221324567|221654000|

I want to match if the line contains \|221.{3}000 followed by \|221.{3}(?!000), that is, data group 221 with three zeros as last digits followed by data group 221 without three zeros as last digit. (Pipe symbol | separates data groups.) This I can easily do with the following regex.

```
^.+\|221.{3}000.*\|221.{3}(?!000)
```

However, what I want to capture is all occurrences of data group 221 with three zeros as last digit (shown bold below).

Group[0]: |221456000

Group[1]: |221654000

Haven't been able to figure out how to match one thing and capture multiple occurrences of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?:(\|221...000).*?)+\|221...(?!000)...(?:(\|221...000).*?)*");
```

where

- `(?:(\|221...000).*?)+` will match and individually capture any `|221...000` data groups preceding the `221...`<strike>`000`</strike>, requiring at least one such data group
- `\|221...(?!000)...` will match but not capture the `221...`<strike>`000`</strike> data group
- `(?:(\|221...000).*?)*` will match and individually capture any `|221...000` data groups succeeding the `221...`<strike>`000`</strike>

**Update**: The above regex captures all `|221...000` occurrences preceding the `221...`<strike>`000`</strike> into one group, and all the `|221...000` occurrences succeeding it into another. If you want to capture them into one group, I would suggest using a named group:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"((?<data>\|221...000).*?)+\|221...(?!000)...((?<data>\|221...000).*?)*");
var captures = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["data"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works. I have more variations which need a little tweaking, but it didn't occur to me to use a capturing group inside a non-capturing group. I need to digest this a bit.

Comment: @Rubio: Cheers. Don't forget to make any nested repetition non-greedy (`.*?`).

Comment: One note, if I have more than one `|221...000` in the end, this will only capture the first. I didn't specify that possibility in my original question, though.

Comment: @Rubio: The regex captures all `|221...000` occurrences, but they're presented as `Captures` within the same `Group`. I'll update the regex to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to match line which fit your demands, and then use another regex (or other technique) to get desired output. It would be more effective than regex alone.

However if you want use just regex, try something like:

```
(?=(^.*?221\d{3}000.*?221\d{3}[1-9]{3}.+))^\w+|(?<=\G)(221.{3}000)|(?<=\G)\w+|(?<=\G)\|
```

- `(?=(^.*?221\d{3}000.*?221\d{3}[1-9]{3}.+))` - positive lookahead for
  your regex
- `^\w+` - beginning of a line with word characters,
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\G)(221.{3}000)` - positive lookbehind for previous match,
  followed by `221.{3}000` part in capturing group
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\G)\w+` - positive lookbehind for previous match, followed by any word
  characters
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\G)\|` - positive lookbehind for previous match,
  followed by escaped logical "OR" character

[DEMO1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3D(%5E.*%3F221%5Cd%7B3%7D000.*%3F221%5Cd%7B3%7D%5B1-9%5D%7B3%7D.%2B))%5E%5Cw%2B%7C(%3F%3C%3D%5CG)(221.%7B3%7D000)%7C(%3F%3C%3D%5CG)%5Cw%2B%7C(%3F%3C%3D%5CG)%5C%7C&i=12345XXX3256%7C221456000%7C352456345%7C221324567%7C221654000%7C%0D%0A%0D%0A12345XXX3256%7C221456000%7C352456345%7C221324000%7C221654000%7C%0D%0A%0D%0A12345XXX3256%7C221456000%7C221654000%7C221324333%7C221654000%7C%0D%0A%0D%0A12345XXX3256%7C221456345%7C352456345%7C221324222%7C221654678%7C%0D%0A%0D%0A12345XXX3256%7C221456000%7C221654000%7C221324333%7C221654000%7C221324333%7C221654000%7C&o=m)
[DEMO2](https://regex101.com/r/iO4tT3/1)

It match separatly different elements of line which fit your demands, but it will also match the `(221\d{3}000)` part in group 2. So if you want to get all `(221\d{3}000)` from given line, you would need use ale matches where group 2 was captured, and to compare whole lines, which are captured in group 1.

It should match all `(221\d{3}000)` no matter how long the line is.
However, direct multiple matching by one group is not possible here